# List AD group that is recursively granted to specific user?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, windows-scripting

I wanted to check and troubleshoot recursive AD group membership for a particular user account or admin groups.

The goal here is to know which AD group is granted multiple times recursively to the user input in the script.

```
Param
(
    [string]$user = 'IT.Support'
)

Function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$Identity)
{
    Process
    {
        $object = Get-ADObject -Identity $Identity -Property memberOf, primaryGroupID, objectSid
        If ($object.objectClass -eq 'group')
        {
            Get-ADGroup -Identity $object -Property memberOf
        }
        Else
        {
            [void]$object.memberof.Add((Get-ADGroup -Identity ($object.objectSid -replace '^(.*?-)([0-9]+)$', ('${1}' + $object.primaryGroupID))).DistinguishedName)
        }
        $object.memberOf | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive
    }
}

Function Get-CanonicalName ([string[]]$DistinguishedName)
{
    foreach ($dn in $DistinguishedName)
    {
        $d = $dn.Split(',')
        $arr = (@(($d | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'DC=' }) | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(3) }))
        [array]::Reverse($arr)
        "{0}/{1}" -f (($d | Where-Object { $_ -match 'dc=' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('DC=', '') }) -join '.'), ($arr -join '/')
    }
}

Get-ADUser -Identity $user |
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive |
        Sort-Object Name |
            Select Name, `
                   GroupCategory, `
                   GroupScope, `
                   @{ N = 'OU Location'; E = { Get-CanonicalName $_.DistinguishedName } },
                   @{ N = 'Parent(s)'; E = { $r = Foreach ($m in $_.memberof) { Get-CanonicalName $m }; $r -join ',' } } |
Out-GridView
```

However, the script above does not show which AD groups are granted multiple times recursively inside another AD groups to the **IT.Support** user.

For example: Input: IT.Support
The desired or excepted output is:

```
Name, GroupCategory, GroupScope, OU Location, Parent (s)
Domain Admins, Security, Universal, domain.com/Production, <Direct membership>
M365 Global Admin, Security, Universal, domain.com/Production, Domain Admins
Regional1 Global Admin, Security, Universal, domain.com/Production, M365 Global Admin
Regional2 Global Admin, Security, Universal, domain.com/Production, M365 Global Admin
```

User IT.Support is direct membership of Domain Admins builtin group.

The Group M365 Global Admin is nested under the Domain Admins group.
Regional1 Global Admin and Regional2 Global Admin group is nested under M365 Global Admin

Therefore I know the membership path or recursively where they are getting the membership from

Comment: "*The script above*" where?

Comment: so ... where is the script? [*grin*] please, add it to your Question. ///// also, do you want a powershell solution or something else? if the 1st, then please remove the `scripting` tags since they are supersets of PoSh. ///// do you need a PoSh v4 solution? if not, then please remove that tag.

Comment: Yes, updated just now :-) sorry for the confusion.